# How to make my applet in my local disk reachable from a URL of Internet?

Tags: url, web, applet

This must be an extremely silly question but  I really cannot find the answer anywhere...

**How to make my applet in my local disk reachable from a URL of Internet?**

I am learning how to deploy applet. Most tutorials tell you how to write the Java code, a html page, and then they show that you can visit the  launches the applet through a web page, which is, actually a local URL starting by file::// ...

I would like to push my applet to Internet so that someone on the other side of the globe can see it through an URL starting by http:://...

Thanks.

Comment: First you should have a webserver=)

Comment: Google: hosting or hosting java

Comment: @E_p you do not need java hosting to host an applet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of applet as special HTML tag (I hope it will be easier to understand ;) ), in order for it to be accessible it has to be hosted someware on the internet (simple hosting will suffice). So you have to write a html page with applet tag upload it and  applet classes to your hosting serwer and voila :)

Comment: Thanks. I don't see how to get the applet hosted. How to?

Comment: If you know how to publish sample html page you only need to read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html